# $L^1$-Minimization on $L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, reference-request, lp-spaces

I want to solve problems of the following sort:
$$
\min_{y \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)} \lVert y \rVert_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}~\\\mathrm{s.t.} \cdots.$$
The constraints do not matter yet, they are only supposed to make the problem well-defined and non-trivial.

My question is if you do know some literature concerning minimization on $L^\infty$ or comparable Banach spaces (existence theorems first and foremost).

The problem seems very difficult as $L^\infty$ is not reflexive/separable.